# Unable to convert a long datatype to xml in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, xmltype

I have an oracle column with a long data type that stores an xml. Now I want to perform the `EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` functions on this column. For this purpose, I need to convert the long to xmltype. But when I do : `xmltype.createxml(long_col_name),` I get :`illegal use of long datatype`
I know long is deprecated, but it is legacy db.So...

EDIT: Upon the suggestion, i tried:

```
SELECT 
EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE (to_lob(long_col_name)), xpath_str) as value_date
FROM table_1;
```

I get:

```
[Error] Execution (2: 24): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG
```

Comment: maybe first convert to CLOB - then to XML

Answer (score 1):

Check this link
[good example](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430)

in short you need to do the following:

```
with xml as 
    (select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select long_col_name from table_1') as xml from dual)

    select extractValue(xs.object_value,'/ROW/long_col_name') as value_date
    from xml x, table(xmlsequence(extract(x.xml,'/ROWSET/ROW'))) xs
    where extractValue(xs.object_value,'/ROW/long_col_name') like '%xxxx%';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better to migrate the LONG column type to CLOB. It will also benefit you in future. then you can use xmltype on the CLOB column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Feel bad about downvoting...but your answer is not helpful to me.